# Where should you place "also" in a sentence? Can it go after a main verb?

Tags: adverbs, adverb-position

Which we interpret *also* as a representative metaphor - is this correct?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

The word "also" can be placed in a few positions in a sentence:

At the beginning of a sentence:

```
Also, I went to the store.
```

After the subject:

```
I also went to the store.
```

Before or after an auxiliary (helping) verb like "will/would" or "have/has":

```
I will also go to the store. I have also gone to the store before.
```

Before or after a main verb:

```
I saw also my friend at the store. I also saw my friend at the store.
```

Using "also" after a main verb is less common and can sound awkward in some cases. It is usually clearer and more natural to place "also" before the main verb. Some examples where placing it after the verb works okay are:

He has also agreed to help with the project. We were also hoping you could join us.
They did also express concern over the new proposal.

However, these could also work with "also" placed before the verb:

He also has agreed to help with the project.
We also were hoping you could join us.
They also did express concern over the new proposal.

So in summary, the most common and natural places to put "also" in a sentence are:

```
At the beginning of the sentence
After the subject
Before an auxiliary (helping) verb
```

Placing "also" after a main verb can sometimes work, but it often sounds less awkward if you put it before the verb instead. If it's not clear or could be misinterpreted, rephrase the sentence with "also" in a position before the verb.

Hope this helps explain where "also" can be placed in a sentence and some examples! Let me know if you have any other questions.